# foundation5 custom orbit left/right arrows

Tags: css, fonts, zurb-foundation, fontello

i have this code, taken from [orbit slideshow custom next prev buttons links left right arrows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17245592/orbit-slideshow-custom-next-prev-buttons-links-left-right-arrows)

```
.orbit-container .orbit-prev span,
.orbit-container .orbit-next span {
    color: red;
    border: none;
    font-size: 70px;
    text-indent: 0;
    margin-top: -32px;
}

.orbit-container .orbit-prev {
    background-color: transparent;
}
.orbit-container .orbit-prev span:before {
    content: "\2039";
}
.orbit-container .orbit-next {
    background-color: transparent;
}
.orbit-container .orbit-next span:before {
    content: "\203A";
}
```

which works, but when i try to replace with my own arrows it is not working!

i have a custom arrows, and have imported them into fontello, so in my fontello.css file i have:

```
.icon-arrow_left_navigate_previous:before { content: '\e846'; } /* '' */
.icon-arrow_right_navigate_next:before { content: '\e847'; } /* '' */
```

and using this as a class works, but when i try to use it within

```
.orbit-container .orbit-prev span:before {
        content: "\e846";
}
.orbit-container .orbit-next span:before {
        content: "\e847";
}
```

this does not work!

but `<i class="icon-arrow_left_navigate_previous"></i>` displays the left arrow.

any advice much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your code actually override original and that your fonts are affecting those elements (check computed style of the element) otherwise those references will refer characters in the different font.